# Error in fn(par, ...) : unused argument (function (..., no.readonly = FALSE)

Tags: r, function

I am defining this function as follows using the data set of the closing prices of the MXNUSD exchange rate. I am making this function to estimate the parameters of a geometric Brownian motion Jump diffusion process:

```
GBMJ <- function(theta){
  dt <- 1/252
  x <- diff(log(usdmxn))
  n <- c(1:length(x))
  mu <- theta[1]
  sigma <- theta[2] 
  lambda <- theta[3] 
  mu_0 <- theta[4] 
  delta <- theta[5] 
  
  p <- rep(0, length(x))
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    p[i] <- (exp(-lambda)*lambda^n[i]/factorial(n[i]))*
      (2*pi*(sigma^2+n[i])*delta^2)^(-0.5)*
      exp((-1/(2*sigma^2*dt+2*n[i]*delta^2))*
            (x[i]-(mu-0.5*sigma^2)*dt-mu_0*n[i])^2)
  }
  L <- log(p)
  LL <- -sum(L)
  
  return(LL)
}
optim(c(1,1,1,1,1), GBMJ, gr=NULL, theta, method = "L-BFGS-B", 
      lower=c(-Inf,0,-Inf,-Inf,0), upper = c(Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf), hessian=T)
```

but I get this error

```
Error in (function (par)  : object 'theta' not found
```

Comment: What is `usdmxn` in your function? It is never defined

Comment: `par` is an R function.  It should not be passed to `optim`.

Comment: `usdmxn` is the exchange rate data that I am using. A vector of the closing prices of the exchange rates.